Golang API stuck using goroutines and context cancellation
I am creating channels in my main function that I want to pass to the method StoreFiles. StoreFiles should either write the result of the operation or an error to the respective channels.
I am passing two channels to the function and I am not sure if this is recommended.
When I tried to hit this API, it works until the eighth or ninth attempt, after which it gets stuck and never responds.
func main() {
    attachmentChan := make(chan []string, 1)
    errorChan := make(chan error, 1)
    attachmentPaths := make([]string, 0)
    contx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx.Context())

    go StoreFiles(&contx, cancel, body, tenant, bucketName, attachmentChan, errorChan)
    select {
    case err := <-errorChan:
        if err != nil {
            return response, err
        }

    case attachmentPaths = <-attachmentChan:
    }
}


Here is the StoreFiles function which I want to run as a separate goroutine:
func StoreFiles(ctx *context.Context, cancel context.CancelFunc, body EmailDto, tenant string, bucketName string, attachmentChan chan []string, errorChan chan error) {
    currentDate := GetFormattedDate()
    saveFolder := bucketName + "/" + tenant + "/" + currentDate

    extensions := strings.Split(constants.AllowedExtensions, ",")

    allowedExtensions := make(map[string]struct{})

    for _, ext := range extensions {
        allowedExtensions[ext] = struct{}{}
    }

    var attachmentPaths []string

    for _, attachment := range body.Attachments {
        // Decode base64 content
        decodedContent, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(attachment.Content)
        if err != nil {
            logger.GetLogger().Errorln(err)
            errorChan <- err
            cancel()
            // return attachmentPaths, err
        }

        ext := GetFileExtension(attachment.Filename)
        trimmedAttachmentFileName := strings.TrimLeft(attachment.Filename, ".") // Trim the leading dot

        fileName := strings.Split(trimmedAttachmentFileName, ".")
        if len(fileName) < 2 {
            // return attachmentPaths, utils.BadRequestError("Invalid file name" + attachment.Filename)
            errorChan <- utils.BadRequestError("Invalid file name" + attachment.Filename)
            cancel()

        }

        if _, ok := allowedExtensions[ext]; !ok {
            logger.GetLogger().Errorln(err)
            errorChan <- utils.BadRequestError("Invalid file extension")
            cancel()

            // return attachmentPaths, utils.BadRequestError("Invalid file extension")
        }

        randomString := random18DigitGenerator()
        fileNameString := strings.TrimSpace(attachment.Filename) + constants.FileNameSeperator + randomString

        filePath := filepath.Join(saveFolder, fileNameString)

        err = WriteToGCS(*ctx, filePath, decodedContent)
        if err != nil {
            logger.GetLogger().Errorln(err)

            errorChan <- errors.New("Error while saving file")
            cancel()

        }

        logger.GetLogger().Infoln("File stored on GCS :", filePath)
        attachmentPaths = append(attachmentPaths, filePath)

    }
    attachmentChan <- attachmentPaths

    // cancel()

    // return attachmentPaths, nil
}


Try race detector

Currently there is a potential for StoreFiles to send 0-many times to errorChan. Attempting to send more than twice (one received, one buffered) will block.

Further to the above, I think you may have misunderstood what Context does. Calling cancel cancels the context (which acts as a signal for anything listening); it does not terminate the go routine (return will do that). Passing cancel into StoreFiles makes little sense (unless main uses the Context elsewhere). There is also no need for a pointer to the Context (Context is an interface).
